# What does syntax of "functionName`literalTemplate`" means?

Tags: typescript

So recently I have stumbled upon syntax that is new to me in Typescript eg:

```
someFunction`Literal template goes here`
```

no parantesis, no nothing. As a result function `someFunction` is called. Does it have some sort of name? Why paranthesis is not required here? Why it does not work for eg string?

Complete code and working (sort of) example

```
function test(v:ReadonlyArray<string>){
  console.log(v);
  console.log(v.length);
}

function test2(v:Readonly<string>){
  console.log(v);
}


console.log("gonna do it");

test`and iv done it
really done it!`;

test2"something else??"; // does not work
```

[TSPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=25&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygCgG4C4BKKAhgCYIA2AngIIBOtRlAPBrTGAOYB8AlAN4AoRIggI0ccigB05OBxw8A3EJFiJ02fOwyUnKAAslAgL4CBoSLATJ0UAEw4CxMmCosobTr0HDRYcZIycgrKpmZ%20ARrBAEQcCGBEiGSIMFDRRgKoGAAGRGAkKdhJCCgpUAK0xORUxWClqQCE2cqZtnbR4gC2KAbsHIgo5GgoAPwj0cpAA)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript) (specifically the bit which says "What is the purpose of template literals (backticks) following a function in ES6?")

Comment: Thank you very much!. So much to learn yet